# Fetching photos and videos from a Facebook event using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-events

I'm attempting to fetch all photos and videos from a Facebook event using the Facebook Graph API.

Currently I'm using the `/{event-id}/feed` endpoint, described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/event/feed

I can get *almost* everything I need from this endpoint by specifying the fields I want, but I'm having trouble getting URL to the the videos in full resolution. I can easily get them by making another API call, but I want to avoid making another API call for all videos, if possible.

Please note that the `/{event-id}/feed` endpoint returns an array of `Post objects`, which is what I'm querying using the `fields` query parameter.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post

Here's the fields I´m specifying when calling the `/{event-id}/feed` endpoint

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{event-id}/feed?fields=attachments,id,created_time,caption,from,name,message,message_tags,source,type,status_type,properties,object_id,picture&access_token={access-token}
```

The `attachments` field gives me image URL of the video in high resolution and the ID of the video itself. This means that I need to make additional API call just to get the video URL in high resolution using the `/{video-id}` endpoint.

```
"attachments": {
        "data": [
           {
              "media": {
                 "image": {
                    "height": 405,
                    "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/s720x720/13433040_10154318390596912_1315696369_n.jpg?oh=46987fa671df2deca3ce935a68e1ff30&oe=58008D60",
                    "width": 720
                 }
              },
              "target": {
                 "id": "10154318389716912",
                 "url": "https://www.facebook.com/{username-removed}/videos/10154318389716912/"
              },
              "type": "video_autoplay",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com/{username-removed}/videos/10154318389716912/"
           }
        ]
     }
```

The `source` field gives me link to the video in low resolution.

```
"source": "https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.1790-2/13543016_152852391800500_1248221173_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjMxMywicmxhIjo1MTIsInZlbmNvZGVfdGFnIjoic3ZlX3NkIn0\u00253D&rl=313&vabr=174&oh=f0f42856741b81030ea529fe89f80834&oe=5771B45B"
```

The `object_id` field gives me the video ID.

The `properties` field gives me the length of the video.

So I'm out of luck. I'm wondering if it's possible to make some nested call that would give me the URL of the high resolution video, or if I could call some endpoint with the video ID that returns 302 redirect to the video. Could I maybe modify the parameters to the source URL?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*...I'm wondering if it's possible to make some **nested** call that would
>   give me the URL of the high resolution video...*"

**Solution** :

To make all the API calls you want at once, you can try **Batch Requests** with Graph API.

See the documentation & examples at : [`Facebook API - Making Multiple Requests`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests)

Quote from the [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests) :

> **"** ... Batching allows you to pass instructions for several operations in a
>   single HTTP request. You can also specify dependencies between related
>   operations (described in a section below). Facebook will process each
>   of your independent operations in parallel and will process your
>   dependent operations sequentially. Once all operations have been
>   completed, a consolidated response will be passed back to you and the
>   HTTP connection will be closed.**"**

As you can see, it is to make multiple requests and create dependencies between them.
 
So when you get the `video_id` you're able request the video right there in the resolution you want.

Comment: Hi @Rui, Welcome to StackOverflow. I hope you don't mind the edit. Just making it a nicer answer. The only small improvement I can think of is, if you provided testable example code yourself, but really it's not needed cos the link explains everything. Good luck.

Comment: This is what I was leaning towards, but I wasn't sure how. It would be awesome if there was an example on how I can batch those requests together, so that the first request would return video IDs that the second request would call, if that makes sense.